# build dynamic MongoDB query to update nested value in dict

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

Considering an object as such:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b4dbf3541e5ae6de394cc99"),
    "active" : true,
    "email" : "admin@something.eu",
    "password" : "$2b$12$5qqD3ZulKI7S6j.Wx513POpCNWRMppE.vY4.3EIZedm109VUPqXoi",
    "badges" : {
        "cnc" : {
            "lvl" : "0"
        },
        "laser" : {
            "lvl" : "0"
        },
        "impression3d" : {
            "lvl" : "0"
        },
        "maker" : {
            "lvl" : "0"
        },
        "electronique" : {
            "lvl" : "0"
        },
        "badge" : {
            "lvl" : 1
        }
    },
    "roles" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b4dbf3541e5ae6de394cc97")
    ]
}
```

I need to change the `lvl` value to anywhere between 0 and 5, not necessarily inregular increments. To do this, the parent object name is passed by a variable, thererfor I'm trying to build a dynamic query for a badge lvl to be changed.

Currently the end of my Flask route looks as so:

```
badge = quiz['badge']
C_user = current_user.get_id()
update = bdd.user.update({"_id": C_user, "badges": { '$elemMatch': {badges : badge}}}, {"$set": { "badges.$.lvl": 3 }}, upsert = True)
```

But with a query of this sort, I receive an error saying:

`pymongo.errors.WriteError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.`

Am I totally wrong thinking I need to use the $elemMatch operator? Is there a way to dynamically target the different badges to increment the inner lvl?

Thank you!

Note: I first attempted this with MongoEngine but it seemed impossible to drill down with it.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this, badges is an document, not an array. try

```
 ...
 {"$set": { "badges.badge.lvl": 3 }} 
 ...
```

But you'll have to explicitely  do this for each badges fields.
The way to use your query is to update your scheme in something like

```
...
"badges" : [
    {name:"cnc", 
        "lvl" : "0"
    },
    {"name":"laser",
        "lvl" : "0"},
    ...
    ]
    ...
```

EDIT : with some updates on your scheme, here's a way to reach your goal :

New datata Schema :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b4dbf3541e5ae6de394cc99"), 
    "active" : true, 
    "email" : "admin@something.eu", 
    "password" : "$2b$12$5qqD3ZulKI7S6j.Wx513POpCNWRMppE.vY4.3EIZedm109VUPqXoi", 
    "badges" : [
        {
            "name" : "cnc", 
            "lvl" : "0"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "laser", 
            "lvl" : "5"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "impression3d", 
            "lvl" : "0"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "maker", 
            "lvl" : "0"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "electronique", 
            "lvl" : "0"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "badge", 
            "lvl" : 1
        }
    ], 
    "roles" : [
        ObjectId("5b4dbf3541e5ae6de394cc97")
    ]
}
```

and here an update query :

```
db['02'].update(
   {_id: ObjectId("5b4dbf3541e5ae6de394cc99")}, // <= here you filter your documents
   { $set: { "badges.$[elem].lvl": "10" } },  // <= use of positionnal operator with identifier, needed for arrayFilters. elem is arbitraty
   { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.name": "laser" } ], // <= update only elements in array that match arrayFilters. 
     upsert: true }
)
```

Comment: Thanks @matthPen, reviewing the data scheme isn't a problem at this point, but I'm now doubting how to structure our collections in consequence: our data seems super simple, a Users collection, with basic login info and roles. We need to be able to attribute badges to each user both manually or through them sucessfully answering quizzes. A badge should be able to have multiple levels as you see above. Would embedded documents of a Badges collection allow us to increment levels in the User document, or is it better to reference them ? Thanks again!

Comment: no need to proceed by reference, i've updated my answer with a more exlpicite example of using an array instead of document fields. Moreover, it is more logical to work with array in this kind of use, and references will add complexity.